# HTML5 history pushState/popState

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, safari, history

I am trying to manipulate browser history. I have been using Firefox so far and I recently switched to Safari. (Version 16.0 (17614.1.25.9.10, 17614))

Since that I noticed a unexpected behavior (at least that I wasn't expecting and that I don't understand). I don't know how to fix it...

[image: Here]

Here is a small diagram of my issue.
The columns are the browser history and the lines are the steps to reproduce the issue.

1. I open a new tab in my safari browser
2. I go to a random website, let say "google.com"
3. Then I go to my test page : index.html

Here is the test page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <script>
        window.history.replaceState({a: 1}, '', window.location.pathname + "?page=1");
        window.history.pushState({a:2 }, '', window.location.pathname + "?page=2");
        window.onpopstate = (event) => { console.log(event.state.a); }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When pressing the back button, Firefox goes to index.html?page=1  as expected (Green arrow (1) on my diagram), while Safari returns to Google (Red arrow (2) on my diagram). Why is it so ? How to fix it ?

I think I am missing a basic point.. but I can't figure out why safari behaves differently. Many thanks in advance !